# UITableView ignoring heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9

After struggling with automatic cell height introduced in iOS 8, I've found out that it's still not mature enough and I need to calculate the size of my cells (that have chat content) manually.

My method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` **is** called, and it returns the correct height (which also changes for multilines etc, no problem with that). I confirm that it's called as I've got a breakpoint inside it. However, my table view still displays like this:

[image]

Some of those texts are actually multiline, and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` returns their correct height. However, my table view just doesn't display it correctly, displaying everything like single line.

I've removed estimated row height property of the table view, I'm not using automatic cell height and I've not implemented esimated row height delegate method. Why are my cells sizing incorrectly?

**UPDATE:** I was using autolayout and I was connecting my text view to the bottom of the container. I've removed the constraint and it now *sometimes* works. Sometimes it does return the correct size, but sometimes, it returns an incorrect size.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems that the problem is related to line break mode. If my text is long and naturally wrapping to the next line, it is calculated correctly. However, if my text contains explicit line breaks, it is calculated incorrectly, causing a multiline text to be calculated like a single line. Here is my code:

```
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
textAttrs = @{
              NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]
              };
NSString *content = message[@"content"];
CGSize fitSize = [content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(availableWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:textAttrs context:nil].size;
```

At this point, size for naturally wrapping long texts are calculated correctly but texts with line breaks in itself are calculated incorrectly. Why?

Comment: How are you calculating the cell height? Can you please show the code?

Comment: @FahriAzimov see my updates.

Comment: what about using a `UILabel` with `numberOfRows` property set to **0**? auto cell height should work well then...

Comment: @AndréSlotta I've avoided that explicitly as it creates all sorts of other glitchy animation problems when inserting rows. So no, that's not an option.

Comment: Once have had a similar problem, and ended up calculating height creating new `UILabel`, setting it's `numberOfLines` to `0`, setting proper font, width and calling `sizeToFit`, and returning height of the label. Maybe, it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the sample project I created: https://github.com/slotti85/AutoCellHeight.

for me the automatic calculation works fine - even with a `UITextView`. in storyboard i **unchecked** the `UITextView`s `User Interaction Enabled` and `Scrolling Enabled` checkboxes.

let me know if I forgot something specific to your project...

hope it helps!